# MSVC do not generate lib via cmake

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

CMakeLists:

```
if (MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
endif()
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

CMake 2.8.12 + MSVC 2015

config outputs:

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG is /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE is /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO is /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL is /MD /O1 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Referred https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-March/027990.html.

> You most likely have not setup your classes and/or function calls to be
>   exported.  If you have no exported classes/functions Visual Studio will not
>   generate an import library for you.

But adding `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON` got the same result.

How to make MSVC generate lib & dll like mingw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `cmake` 2.8 to 3.4 solves the problem.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/release/3.4.html?highlight=windows_export_all_symbols